# How to remove dry erase marker from a refrigerator?

Tags: cleaning, refrigerator

Trying to remove dry-erase marker from a fridge. I've tried and failed with ammonia, wd40, olive oil, comet, vinegar, old hydrogen peroxide (could be broken down/too old), dish soap and water.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Baking soda with a little water scrubbed finally worked! Came off immediately and easily as I worked it across the surface. Toothpaste (aqua-fresh) worked okay but the baking soda has been by-far the easiest.

Following up the baking soda with a whitening toothpaste (think it was Sensodyne whitening) cleaned and restored it to the original condition. Took a little while, scrubbed over with the baking soda until most of it was gone or faded. Wiped it down with soap and water then followed up with the toothpaste to finish the remaining residue and hard to reach spots.

Comment: Glad you found a solution. You can choose your own answer as the best one, if you like.

Answer (score 2):

Isopropyl alcohol might work. I've had good luck with it removing permanent marker.

Comment: I have had good luck with IPA Also. +

Comment: Thanks BillOer, tried isopropyl alcohol and it does work but with significant effort--the baking soda seems to work a little better, not sure why. Unless the marker is fresh (which I haven't tried, these are months-old marks).

Comment: @jimmont, the baking soda probably works better because it's a bit abrasive. I've had good luck using isopropyl alcohol to remove permanent marker and inked expiration dates on plastic jars I reuse (the Kirkland cashew jars are great for screws and stuff).

Answer (score 1):

I used a mixture of baking soda and rubbing alcohol and it worked really well. Just by making a paste and rubbing it in made the old marker come off quickly and with no residue or leave-behind. It may create toxic fumes, so make sure to wear a mask or work in a well ventilated area.